# php random image function returns the same image if function is called more than once, any way to prevent this?

Tags: php, arrays, function

i have the following array which stores my photos

```
$photos = array(
    "karate" => array('karate1.gif','karate2.png','karate3.gif','karate4.gif'),
    "judo" => array("judo1.png","judo2.png","judo3.png","judo4.png"),
    "kickboxing" => array("kb1.gif","kb2.png","kb3.gif","kb4.png")
);
```

and i have my function

```
function rndImage($category, $photos)
{
    echo "<p>".count($photos[$category]);
    $num = mt_rand(0, count($photos[$category])-1);
    $varIMG = $photos[$category][$num];
    echo $category." = ".$varIMG."<br />";
    if(($key = array_search($varIMG, $photos[$category])) !== false)
    {
        array_splice($photos[$category], $key, 1);
    }
    echo count($photos[$category]);
    return $varIMG."</p>";
}
```

now this works fine if i only call the function once, however if i call it several times on the page like so

```
rndImage("karate",$photos);
rndImage("karate",$photos);
rndImage("karate",$photos);
rndImage("judo",$photos);
rndImage("kickboxing",$photos);
```

i often get results where the image returned is the same like so

```
4karate = karate1.gif3
4karate = **karate3.gif**3
4karate = **karate3.gif**3
4judo = judo.png3
4kickboxing = kb1.gif3
```

its is removing the selected image from the array each time the function is ran but it resets each time the function is run too meaning duplicate images can be returned.

Is there a way i can keep a track on which images have been used and therefor not allow them to be chosen next time the function is run on that page?

any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks

Comment: Well, it's *random*. Perhaps you're rather looking for *shuffling* a list of images into a random order…?

Comment: thats an interesting idea, what would you suggest? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `$photos` argument a reference, so that the removals you make on that array apply to the original array, not a copy made by the function (PHP has this habit). Add the ampersand(`&`):

```
function rndImage($category, &$photos) {
    // ...etc
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, this kind of works, it removes the image from the array & remembers it next time the function is called meaning the same image wont appear twice, the main issue is that this code now stops it being a randomly generated function, the outcome is the same every time. for example i now get `4karate = karate1.gif3
4karate = karate3.gif3
3karate = karate2.gif2 2karate = karate4.gif1
4judo = judo.png3
4kickboxing = kb1.gif3` every time, the randomness is no longer a feature of the function. Is there a way to get this to randomise the images each time the page loads? thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you report: when I run this code, the produced order is different most of the time. You could look into calling [mt_srand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php), but the documentation says PHP does this automatically already....

Comment: ah i had an extra bit of code in, which i added when trying one of the suggestions below, this was causing the issue. have removed the code and it now works superbly!!! thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [mt_srand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php) before `mt_rand` to seed the better random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

You can show images sequentially rather than randomizing it to have full control on what is shown.

Have modified your code a bit.

```
<?php

$photos = array(
    "karate" => array('karate1.gif','karate2.png','karate3.gif','karate4.gif'),
    "judo" => array("judo1.png","judo2.png","judo3.png","judo4.png"),
    "kickboxing" => array("kb1.gif","kb2.png","kb3.gif","kb4.png")
);

$show_image = array(); // Maintain counter for image to be shown

rndImage("karate",$photos);
rndImage("karate",$photos);
rndImage("karate",$photos);
rndImage("karate",$photos);
rndImage("karate",$photos);
rndImage("judo",$photos);
rndImage("kickboxing",$photos);

function rndImage($category, $photos)
{
    global $show_image;

    if(!isset($show_image[$category]))
    {
        // Initially first image will be shown.
        $show_image[$category] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // Increment counter by 1 to display next image.
        // If it exceeds the total images, reset the counter to 1

        $show_image[$category] = ($show_image[$category] == count($photos[$category])) ? 1 : $show_image[$category] + 1;
    }

    $num = $show_image[$category] - 1;
    $varIMG = $photos[$category][$num];

    echo $category." = ".$varIMG.PHP_EOL;

    return $varIMG;
}
?>
```

> Output
>
> karate = karate1.gif
>
> karate = karate2.png
>
> karate = karate3.gif
>
> karate = karate4.gif
>
> karate = karate1.gif
>
> judo = judo1.png
>
> kickboxing = kb1.gif

*[Working Example](https://eval.in/705429)*